# Algolia highlighResult or snippetResult only what matches

Tags: highlighting, algolia

If I search for "brown" I would like to have all or any of my results that contain "brown" within them only highlight that section.

Currently if I were to search "brown" my results appear like this (bold = highlighted)

**brown**
**brownies**

When I would like the result to be

**brown**
**brown**ies

Any suggestions on how I could make this happen?
I am currently using snippetResults and the object for brownies would say    `matchLevel: "full", value: "<em>brownies</em>` when it is not actually a full match.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is actually to highlight only the matching part. To help you more on that, I'd need to have more informations like the name of your index and its configuration. Could you send us an email at support@algolia.com, we would be happy to help.

Comment: I sent an email with our index and a link back to this stackoverflow question. Thank you!